# Passing Security to a external link from Aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to redirect to an external link(basically an javascript application).
I want to authenticate the redirected application using passed credentials from the aspx page.The javascript application is using Web APIs as back end.Could you suggest me any ways to do that.

Comment: Do you mean external login provider like Facebook, Google using OAuth 2?

Comment: Do your authentication from your aspx code behind either database or Oauth then pass go to  the external link

Comment: @yogeh.yes the authentication is already done on aspx page & then I am redirecting to another URL through a link on aspx & trying to pass the authentication as well.

Comment: @Win. The authentication is already done on aspx page. I want to pass the authentication to the redirected application URL that the user don't have to relogin.